# Android acessing MainActivity from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My application crashes after click the button, but the code executes properly.

```
public void makeLead(View v) throws Exception {
    try {
       RegisterTimer rt = new RegisterTimer();
       rt.ma = this;
       rt.execute(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void log(String msg)
{
    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    tv.append(msg);
}
private class RegisterTimer extends AsyncTask {
    public MainActivity ma;


    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        ma.log("ausd");
        return null;
    }
}
```

`makeLead` is `onClick` event. Method ma.log generates an error but works properly (msg added to `textEdit`). When I delete ma.log, app doesn't crash. I have no logs in my AndroidStudio so I can't see error message. What's wrong ?

Comment: There is no problem with the initialization of `MainActivity` in `RegisterTimer`. You have initialized properly at `rt.ma = this`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by @Raghunandan you have not initialized ma.

next is you cannot access view in background thread.

if your thread class is inside of MainActivity class then you can use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ma.log("ausd");

            }
        });
```

inside doInBackground method to update view.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update ui from a `doInbackground`. Initializing ma is not required

Make AsyncTask an inner class of Activity and update ui in `onPostExecute`

or use interface as a callback to the activity

Edit:

To make it clear

1. Make asynctaks an inner class of activity. Declare textview as a instance variable. Return result in doInbackground

In Activity

```
     TextView tv;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancestate)  
     super.onCreate(savedInstancestate); 
     setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
      tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Then

```
     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(Void objects) {
       // some background computation
     return "ausd";
     }
```

1. In `onpostExecute`

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
    super.onPostExecute();
     tv.append(result);
    }
   ```

Also you need

```
 private class RegisterTimer extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {   // args missing
```

Comment: I think OP has initialized `MainActivity` properly inside `RegisterTimer`. see the initialization at `rt.ma = this`...

Comment: @GopalRao that is not required at all. can update ui in onPostExecute if its a inner class

Comment: but OP modifying UI in a background Thread. i.e. he is calling in `doInBackground()`...

Comment: @GopalRao i have mentioned update ui  in `onPostExecute`

Comment: A different acceptance from the OP... can't imagine

Comment: @GopalRao hmm. But i don't think you need to intialize ma and also why use runOnUiThread when you have onPostExecute that does the job

Comment: Yeah... No need to initialize `MainActivity` but I said to initialize because he is using `ma.log()` and what is the use of `AsyncTask` here? is it necessary for just returning `String`?

Comment: @GopalRao if you ask me not there is no background computation done so there is not need for asynctask in the first place

Answer (score 2):

You can not touch the `View`s in a non UI Thread.

and you are appending text to `TextView` in a background `Thread` which is not allowed.

and I hope there is no problem with the initialization of `MainActivity` inside `RegisterTimer` as you are not creating the instance of `Activity` manually. You are in correct way with the initialization `rt.ma = this`. 
and why do you need `AsyncTask` just for changing the text of a `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

Your method log is public, you don't need to make an object of the `MainActivity` class to access it, instead you can call it directly. Also you need to add some template after your `ASYNC` task, if you want to pass some input to your background process, you are using `ASYNC` task in a wrong way.